# C# - WINAPI CB_SETCURSEL not working as expected

Tags: c#, winapi, combobox

So I am trying to update a combobox in another application programmatically.  The application I am updating has a combobox, some textboxes, and a number of checkboxes.  **Depending on the item selected in the combobox certain checkboxes will become enabled or disabled**.  The problem I am having is that, although I can change the current item in the combobox,  the gui doesn't seem to be updated the checkboxes accordingly.

Here is my code

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);


const int CB_SETCURSEL = 0x014E;

static void Main(string[] args)
{

       var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("path");

        // Get an object that contains all the process resources
        Process rtugen = Process.Start(startinfo);

        // wait until the process has a main window handle
        while (rtugen.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            rtugen.Refresh();
        }


        IntPtr hWnd = rtugen.MainWindowHandle;

        IntPtr controllerType = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", null);

        SendMessage(controllerType, CB_SETCURSEL, 12, "");

        int send_cbn_selchange = MakeWParam((int)controllerType, CBN_SELCHANGE);
        int i = SendMessage(hWnd, 0x111, send_cbn_selchange,0);

}

    static int MakeWParam(int loWord, int hiWord)
    {
        return (loWord & 0xFFFF) + ((hiWord & 0xFFFF) << 16);
    }
```

So, the above code does update the combobox, but the GUI doesn't seem to update the checkboxes after the update is made.  I monitored the combobox change in spy++ and it showed me the same command being sent.  Any ideas on what is going wrong?

Comment: UIAutomation will make this significantly easier/less hacky.  The parent window wants a CBN_SELCHANGE notification, thats what it uses to identify a change has been made.

Comment: Yea, I will consider looking into the UIAutomation.  I also edited the code to show me sending the parent window the CBN_SELCHANGE notification, which still does not work.  Could you provide some code into the correct way to send a CBN_SELCHANGE notification?

Comment: The correct way is to use UI Automation

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found this solution online to change the value of the combobox so that the application recognizes the change. Once you have a handle on the combobox you can use the WM_KEYDOWN msg to simulate key down action.

```
 [DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);


const int CB_SETCURSEL = 0x014E;
const int VK_DOWN = 0x28;
const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
static void Main(string[] args)
{

       var startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("path");

        // Get an object that contains all the process resources
        Process rtugen = Process.Start(startinfo);

        // wait until the process has a main window handle
        while (rtugen.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            rtugen.Refresh();
        }


        IntPtr hWnd = rtugen.MainWindowHandle;

        IntPtr controllerType = FindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", null);

        SendMessage(controllerType, CB_SETCURSEL, 0, "");
        for (int i = 0; i < Index; i++)
            SendMessage(controllerType, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0);

    }
```

Comment: This sort of hackers is all pervasive online but it is not how to do it. Use UI Automation.

Comment: Do you know of any good sources to learn about UI Automation?  Where did you learn?

Comment: Start with some websearch

Comment: I have never used UI Automation, but based on MSDN it says: "UI Automation is designed for experienced C/C++ developers. In general, developers need a moderate level of understanding about Component Object Model (COM) objects and interfaces, Unicode, and Windows API programming. " The application I am dealing with does NOT implement COM.

Comment: Your C# program will be able to automate this combo box with ease using UI Automation. If you prefer to hack though, go ahead.

Comment: An example would be nice?  As I have mentioned I am not familiar with UI Automation, but from what I have read it requires that the application I am automating implement the IUIAutomation interface (which is not the case for me and I am not in a position to make code changes to this application) unless you have heard otherwise or yourself written an application that is a UI Automation provider.

Comment: Win32 controls support the interfaces.